# В коде Unreachable code

Tags: android-fragment, android

Учусь писать rss news. В этом коде:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return view;

        if (savedInstanceState == null){addRssFragment();}
    }

    private void addRssFragment() {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        RssFragment fragment = new RssFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }}
```

В этой строчке:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){addRssFragment();} - Unreachable code
```

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно?

Comment: Это код который никогда не выполнится, потому что у Вас перед ним return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот участок кода никогда не будет выполнен, так как у вас перед этим идет возврат значения и выход из метода соответственно